# How do I open the Xbox 360 guide on Xbox One?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-one, backwards-compatibility

I know there's some way to do this, but when I press the guide button, a short hold goes to the Xbox One home and a long hold goes to turn the controller off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Press the select and start buttons simultaneously.

Comment: How come it says you answered this 1 second before you asked it?

Comment: Because I answered it when I asked it. (Better than making others search through the rest of the Internet.)

Comment: But 1 second BEFORE you asked it? Must be a bug...

Comment: @2xedo. It's like Sean said. When you answer your own question before posting it, stuff like that happens. It might be a bug or by design (probably a bug), but it doesn't cause any problems, so it will probably never be fixed.

Comment: @Nolonar That makes sense.

Comment: I doubt this needs to be in big, bold text.